# QTextEditor returns quotes as question marks in QT Ruby

Tags: ms-word, text-editor, copy-paste, quotes, qtruby

When I copy and paste from a Word document into a QT `TextEditor`, It seems to look fine. But when I try to access the text using `toPlainText` or `toHTML`, it returns the text with all of the quotes (double and single) as question marks. Is there a way around this? I am using the qt4-qtruby bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the quotes used in Word aren't actually ASCII quote characters - They are some kind of funky unicode character that kind of looks like a quote.

For HTML, if you use UTF-8 encoding, it should work fine.  For plain text though you're pretty much out of luck.

Here's a [nice page with some more info](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a QTextEdit. I think the problem is encoding related. Try saving the word document as plain text and trying the same. If it is important to interoperate with word, I think you will have to figure out how to change the encoding on copy-paste.

**Edit**
Do post whatever solution you use finally. I am very interested.

I am new to QT as well and this is just my opinion.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I haven't found a satisfactory answer yet. But at this point there seems to be a incompatibility in the ruby bindings that link in the QT libraries. If you're using just straight c or c++ I am sure you won't see this issue, or at least you can address it by setting encoding.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll keep looking for an answer too. Let me know if you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `toPlainText()` it returns a `QString`. `QString` is internally unicode so as long as the data is inside the `QString` it's supposed to be OK. If you get the data out of the `QString` using `toAscii()` then that's where the bad conversion takes place.
If this theory is correct, use `toUtf8()` instead of `toAscii()` on the `QString`.